# Which library I need to add? : error LNK2019

Tags: c++, lnk2019

> Error 20  error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   CAnyseeUSBTVControllerDlg::CAnyseeUSBTVControllerDlg(class
>   CWnd *)"
>   (??0CAnyseeUSBTVControllerDlg@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "int __cdecl
>   Init(void)"
>   (?Init@@YAHXZ)    anyseeUSBTVControllerDlg.obj    anyseee30

I have this error when I want compile my win32 dll project in visual studio 2008.

Also second error (propably linked with first):

> Error 21  fatal error LNK1120: 1
>   unresolved
>   externals .\Debug/anyseeUSBTVController.exe   anyseee30

Which library I need to add to linker? I've read that it is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the library that contains the `CAnyseeUSBTVControllerDlg` class. Since a web search for `CAnyseeUSBTVControllerDlg` returns nothing, the library seems to be a private library without public documentation.

Comment: Mayby, but declaration of class CAnyseeUSBTVControllerDlg I have in header file

Answer (score 0):

If you only have class declaration and do not have class implementation, then you need to check with whoever gave you that header file. Ask them for the library.
Generally, Libraries come with header files. Implementation will be inside the library.
By including those header files, we can use library classes/functions.

If header file is written by you, then you need to implement the class in a c++ file.